# Echelon form of a matrix

Tags: matrix-rank

As far as I know each matrix has a unique echelon form. But sometimes I find more than one when I change my row operation. Why does it happen?  Or is getting a unique echelon form just for row reduced echelon form?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the Echelon form is not unique, but RREF is unique. It happens because what you get is not computationally independent of the algorithm you use to compute it. More specifically, the rows need not be linearly independent. When you reduce to RREF, they are linearly independent. (sorry for editing so many times, I just wanted to be as clear as possible)

Comment: Reference: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m308w02/online/answers1-2.html